# Unexpected result in 64-bit integer equation

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I'd like to ask a question about the following equation:

```
 value = (floor(((value - min) + (step / 2)) / step) * step) + min;
```

I use it to limit an incoming value to a step size given a minimum for unsigned integral types.

I've been using it for some time and works well until I recently discovered that it can give unexpected results. The following program demonstrates my point:

```
// test.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
  uint64_t value = 2305913515935801433;
  uint64_t min = value;
  uint64_t step = 1;

  uint64_t result1 = (value - min) + (step / 2);
  uint64_t result2 = ((value - min) + (step / 2)) / step;
  uint64_t result3 = floor(((value - min) + (step / 2)) / step);
  uint64_t result4 = (floor(((value - min) + (step / 2)) / step) * step);
  uint64_t result5 = (floor(((value - min) + (step / 2)) / step) * step) + min;

  uint64_t result6_ = (floor(((value - min) + (step / 2)) / step) * step);
  uint64_t result6 = result6_ + min;

  printf("result1 = %" PRIu64 " (0x%" PRIX64 ")\n", result1, result1);
  printf("result2 = %" PRIu64 " (0x%" PRIX64 ")\n", result2, result2);
  printf("result3 = %" PRIu64 " (0x%" PRIX64 ")\n", result3, result3);
  printf("result4 = %" PRIu64 " (0x%" PRIX64 ")\n", result4, result4);
  printf("result5 = %" PRIu64 " (0x%" PRIX64 ")\n", result5, result5);
  printf("result6 = %" PRIu64 " (0x%" PRIX64 ")\n", result6, result6);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled under 64-bit Linux using:

```
g++ -Wall --std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
```

The result:

```
result1 = 0 (0x0)
result2 = 0 (0x0)
result3 = 0 (0x0)
result4 = 0 (0x0)
result5 = 2305913515935801344 (0x2000402020202000)
result6 = 2305913515935801433 (0x2000402020202059)
```

As you can see, the result with the complete equation (result5) is wrong and somehow has the last byte cleared. The last, two-part result (result6) is correct.

I cannot explain the reason why the fifth result fails. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

floor is converting to a floating point double which causes precision loss.

A typical floating point double in c++ is accurate for integers less than 2 raised to the 53rd power. A 64 bit unsigned integer can be larger than that.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that when you call `floor` on your intermediate result, it's returned as a `double`. When you do the addition to `min` in the same equation the math is done as `double` math, which results in a loss of data when you convert `2305913515935801433` to a double.

However when you assign the result of `floor` to a temporary it reverts back to a `uint64_t` allowing the final result to be computed with integral math and losing no precision.

However all that said since you're doing the entire equation in integer math the call to floor is completely unneeded. The language already specifies that integer division truncates down so there's no need to use `floor` at all. And when you remove the `floor` call the original equation will all be done in 64-bit integer math resulting in the correct answer in a single expression.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. The calculation is normally templated, where the template argument is 'uint64_t' in the example that caused trouble. For floating-point types the floor is necessary.